# Error logging to file not working in javascript windows store app

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, winjs, windows

I am trying to write console log to a file. I tried this way and a log file is created but no contents are appended to it.Calling it at the start of the app. Am i doing something wrong.

```
function startFileLog() {
// choose where the file will be stored:
var fileDestination = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder;

var logger = new WinJS.Promise(function (complete) {
    var logfilename = new Date().toISOString().replace(/[:-]/g, "");
    logfilename = "log-" + logfilename + ".log";
    fileDestination.createFileAsync(logfilename,
        Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.generateUniqueName)
          .done(function (file) {
            complete(file);
        });
});

var actionFn = function (message, tag, type) {
    logger.then(function (file) {
        var m = WinJS.Utilities.formatLog(message, tag, type);
        Windows.Storage.FileIO.appendTextAsync(file, m).done();
    });
};

WinJS.Utilities.startLog({ action: actionFn });
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and it worked fine when I logged using WinJS.log (although the results are better if you call appendLinesAsync(file, [m]) instead. How are you trying to make log entries? console.log won't go into this mechanism, only WinJS.log.

Comment: I was expecting log from the javascript console to be wriiten to the file. Is that possible. Please share if you know.

Comment: So long as the logging is being done from WinJS.log, then it should go into your file. You'd get a bunch of stuff from the WinJS library itself this way. However, any calls your app or other libraries make to console.log will not automatically go through WinJS.log, even if it shows up on the console. You'd need to override the console.log function itself to reroute it.